how to do this motion blur effect using ffmpeg?
There's a super clean motion blur transition between words I've seen people do on captions that looks like this (10 sec example): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ygbCgz61fXMk4JeCKQiImRrDlKtE6qFz/view?usp=sharing
the way people actually do this is by taking exporting a transparent video with just the captions on it, then applying a motion blur effect in capcut on the video then overlaying that video on their source video.
So I want to do the same thing in ffmpeg. I've played around with a few different settings but haven't found the right fit yet.
The settings people use on capcut are:
blur: 90
blend: 10
directions: both
speed: Twice
does anyone know the exact command + settings to achieve the same effect using ffmpeg?
I've tried doing a blend on a few frames using ffmpeg but the effect just doesn't look clean. And when I do speed and blur in my command it applies to the entire video instead of just the transition
